# How to upload to Database SQL Server? where is the possible coding error?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
    string fname=""; <----- Global variable
    HtmlInputFile file = (HtmlInputFile)place.FindControl("f_upload");

    if (filename.Value.Equals(""))
    {
        span1.InnerHtml = "<b>Error Message : A File Name must be enter </b>";
        return;
    }


    if (file.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        try
        {

            file.PostedFile.SaveAs("c:\\WADUploadFile\\" + filename.Value);

            fname = "c:\\WADUploadFile\\" + filename.Value;
            //checking fname value
            Response.Write(fname);

            span1.InnerHtml = "File is uploaded successfully to" + "<b>C:\\WADUploadFile\\" +
                filename.Value + "</b>at the server";
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            span1.InnerHtml = "Error occured while saving file to" +
                "<b>c:\\WADUploadFile\\" + filename.Value + "</b><br/>" + "[ " +
                exc.ToString() + " ]";
        }
    }


    string sql1 = "INSERT INTO Thread (Th_id, Th_poster, Th_date) VALUES (@id, @poster, @date)";

    string sql2 = "INSERT INTO ThreadCommend(C_id,C_content,C_upload,T_id,Th_id)Values(@Cid,@Ccontent,@Cupload,@Tid,@Thid)";


    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql1, con);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", threadId);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@poster", tempPoster);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now);

    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql2, con);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cid", commendId);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ccontent", txt);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cupload", fname.ToString());
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tid", topicId);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Thid", threadId);




    //SqlDataAdapter daInsert = new SqlDataAdapter();
    //daInsert.InsertCommand = cmdInsertDesc.ToString();
    int x = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    con.Open();
    int y = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();   <--- Error appear here 



    string note = "Topic added sucussfully";
    if (x > 0)
    {
        Response.Write(note.ToString());

        //Response.Write(x.ToString());
    }

    if (y > 0)
    {
        Response.Write(note.ToString());

        //Response.Write(x.ToString());
    }

    con.Close();
```

My question is: how do I upload to the SQL Server database? Is it a problem to `ExecuteNonQuery` 2 times with each different object?

The error message:

> SqlException was unhandled by user code
>   The parameterized query '(@Cid int,@Ccontent nvarchat(6),@Cupload
>   nvarchar(4000),@Tid int expects the parameter '@Cupload' which was not
>   supplied.

What is wrong with my code that I can't add add data to database? T.T

Comment: What is your `cmd2` looks like after you add your parameter values? What is the type of `C_upload` column and what is the value of `fname.ToString()`?

Comment: string fname=""; <----- Global variable

file.PostedFile.SaveAs("c:\\WADUploadFile\\" + filename.Value);

            fname = "c:\\WADUploadFile\\" + filename.Value;
            //checking fname value
            Response.Write(fname);

SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql2, con);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cid", commendId);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ccontent", txt);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cupload", fname.ToString());
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tid", topicId);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Thid", threadId);

@ Soner Gonul > pls refer next commend

Comment: What is that code for? o.O

Comment: sucussfully -> successfully

Comment: @ Soner Gonul > as you can see from the code of cmd2, this is  the command. however the entire cmd2 failed to update the database, which meant is completely no update.
For cmd1, the string command is successfully updated into the table without problem.

C_upload nchar(300) set in database, purpose is to save upload directory string.

fname is in string format, as i expected it to hold ""c:\\WADUploadFile\\" + filename.Value" this value, where filename is the short name of the file that is named by the user in a textbox

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread and Im sure you found a fix but it looks like you could have an injection problem. try giving the sqlcommand a data type for each parameter using a SqlDataAdapter.

not sure what your data types are but it should look something like this. Also utilize the using statement so you don't have to close/dispose the connections

```
          using (con)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter cmd1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
            cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql1, con);
            cmd1.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = threadId;
            cmd1.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@poster", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tempPoster;

            cmd1.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlDataAdapter cmd2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
            cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql2, con);
            cmd2.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Cid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = commendId;
            cmd2.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Ccontent", SqlDbType.Nvarchar).Value = txt;
            cmd2.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Cupload", SqlDbType.Nvarchar).Value = fname.ToString();
            cmd2.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Tid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = topicId;
            cmd2.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Thid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = threadId;

            cmd2.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```